# How would you take a value from a list and assign it to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just wondering how I could take a value from the list in rolls and assign it to a variable to use within the rest of my code.

```
import random

def dice_roll(number):
    if number == 12:
        number = random.randint(1,12)
        print(number)
        return number
    elif number == 6:
        number = random.randint(1,6)
        print(number)
        return number
    else:
        number == 4
        number = random.randint(1,4)
        print(number)
        return number

print("12 sided")
print("6 sided")
print("4 sided")

rolls = {4: [], 6: [], 12: []} # dictionary to hold rolls
while True:
    roll = int(input("Which dice would you like to roll? --> ")) # store die size
    rolls[roll].append(dice_roll(roll)) # roll and add to dictionary
    doRepeat=input("Go again? --> ")
    if doRepeat == "no":
        break 
    print(rolls)
```

Comment: `my_var = rolls[roll][roll_index]`? That's the best I can give you given the vagueness of the question

Answer (score 1):

Dead @user3119844.

I think your question was a little weird since it is not coherent with the code present.

By the code you seem to be a fairly skilled python programmer. So either I haven't understood the question or it is just weird.

Even though, it seems to me the the rolls dictionary holds 3 lists (related to 3 different dices) and each list holds a few values. In python you use [ ]'s (brackets) to access values by its index. So pick up a variable name, say `v` for instance, then:

```
v=rolls[diceNumber][rollIndex]
```

where `diceNumber` is either 4,6 or 12 and `rollIndex` is the number of the nth roll you're interested in.

Hope it helps